# Can switch statements use variables?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

Below is code that declares two int variables and tries to use them in a switch statement. Is this a legal operation in C++? If not, why not?

```
int i = 0;
int x = 3;
switch (i)
{
    case x:
    // stuff
    break;

    case 0:
    // other stuff
    break;
}
```

Comment: You can provide any expression you like to the `switch` - so `i` or even `i * 2` etc. all fine, but the `case` values have to be compile time constant expressions, so your `x` is not legal but 0 is.

Comment: what happen if you reassign x to 0 before the switch case?

Comment: "CASE" does not make any memory reference assigned by a pointer or by a variable. When you say: case x: this tells the switch statement that I have a value called "X" and I am expecting an input whose value is X or rather string "X". It only expects any value such as a string, int, float or double and it will process it without making any reference to a memory location.

Comment: @Juniar "expects any value such as a string, int, float or double" - `switch` only works for integral types... i.e. `bool`, `char`, [`short`/`long`] [`unsigned`] `int`, an `enum`, or a class that can be contextually implicitly converted to any of those, but *not* any type of string, `float`, nor `double`.

Comment: @TonyD So you can still issue a string value such as Colors: red, blue, green etc. But only with an enum declaration before the switch statement.

Comment: @Juniar: they're identifiers for the enumerators, not "strings" which is used for runtime textual content

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `case` label must be an **integral constant expression**, so your example is invalid. But if `x` were changed to:

```
const int x = 3;
```

then it's valid.

Answer (score 3):

> Can switch statements use variables?

Yes. This is fine,

```
int i = 0;
switch (i) {
}
```

But, `case` statements cannot use variables (they must be constant).

```
case 0:
  // first
  break;
case 1:
  // second
  break;
default:
  // other
```

Comment: But in C++, a variable can be a constant:-).  The requirement is that the case statement evaluate to an integral constant expression.  So even things like `case i + 3:` are valid, _if_ `i` is declared `const`.  Or in C++11, `case g():`, provided that `g` is defined `constexpr`.